# Opening Windows 10 application with custom .exe target addition globally

Tags: windows-10

**Problem:** I created a [custom dark theme for TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/660190/273733) (a LaTeX editor) that I am happy with but I am running into an issue when opening files with the `.tex` file extension in folders when TeXworks is not activated. I changed via properties my TeXworks toolbar shortcut to append this code to the Target:

`C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\texworks.exe -stylesheet "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Programming\LaTeX\CSS Styles\darkbg.css"`

[image]

where `darkbg.css` is the custom style file that enables the TeXworks editor dark theme. I also appended `-stylesheet "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Programming\LaTeX\CSS Styles\darkbg.css"` to my desktop shortcut of TeXworks which when opening `.tex` files within folders still opened with the default white theme.

Seeing that they were all calling the same `.exe`, I found the location of the TeXworks executable in `C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\` but when opening the properties, I cannot see a way to append the `-stylesheet` path to it to set it globally:

[image]

The advanced properties do not glean anything useful.

**Question:** How can I change the `texworks.exe` executable to launch with the addition of the `-stylesheet "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Programming\LaTeX\CSS Styles\darkbg.css` path or via any alternative way? It is only a minor issue as I can open a TeXworks window, then open the file and it automatically loads the dark theme but I would prefer for it not to be like this if possible please!

This is my first question here and I am more used to TeX.SE question etiquette so if you need anything further please ask.

**Edit:** When changing the registry key found here:

[image]

from:

```
"C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\texworks.exe" "%1"
```

to:

```
"C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\texworks.exe -stylesheet "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Programming\LaTeX\CSS Styles\darkbg.css"" "%1"
```

this window opens when trying to open `.tex` files:

[image]

and clicking okay does not load the file at all. I am assuming I have edited the registry entry incorrectly, I do not know the purpose of the "%1" either, is this what I append to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the command that is associated with all
`.tex` files, which requires registry modifications.
Ensure you have backups before doing any registry modifications.

I don't have your software installed on my computer, but this is the
general way of doing it :

- Run `regedit`
- Position to the key `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tex`
- You will see on the right a key named `(Default)`
- Double-click the key and copy its value, then click Cancel
- If the value you copied was, say, `abcdefg`, find on the left
  a key by that name, meaning named `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\abcdefg`
- Drill-down by opening this key - its sub-keys contain the verbs that
  can be executed on `.tex` files
- The sub-keys you are interested in may be called `shell` or `open`
  or `view` or `edit`. If unsure, do all of them as follows
- Open the sub-key, to find a sub-sub-key named `command`
- This key will have a `(Default)` value of type REG_EXPAND_SZ that
  contains the command to be executed
- Double-click the value and add your parameter to the command
- Click OK to terminate - the effect of the change should be immediate.

If the registry entries for `.tex` are different from my above
description, add to your post their screenshots so I can help.

---

Note: the "%1" means the parameter, which in this case means the file.

Your command had unbalanced double-quotes (`"`).
The command should be:

```
"C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\texworks.exe" -stylesheet "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Programming\LaTeX\CSS Styles\darkbg.css" "%1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am going to edit into my question some details now, your description was accurate but I am not sure I have edited the key correctly as it shows a blank file image instead of TeXworks icon and doesn't open

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: Your edit did the trick, I will award the bounty later when I am allowed to, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome - glad to be of help.