# Modified Windows 10 registry and now get this error popup message

Tags: windows-10, texlive

I asked a question a while ago ([Opening Windows 10 application with custom .exe target addition globally](https://superuser.com/q/1746673/1735744)) which worked perfectly for TeXlive 2022. I have updated to TeXlive 2023, followed the answer by @harrymc, but now I receive this random pop-up box that I do not understand:

[image]

I tried Googling for that exit code but it seems a bit strange and non-typical. The TeXworks application opens correctly with my stylesheet loaded, but I have to close this box and I do not understand what is happening.

My registry entry looks like this:

[image]

```
"C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\texworks.exe" -stylesheet "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Programming\LaTeX\CSS Styles\darkbg.css" "%1"
```

which is in the format specified in the linked questions answer. My shortcut icon (on my desktop and toolbar) has this "Target:" `C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\texworks.exe -stylesheet "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Programming\LaTeX\CSS Styles\darkbg.css"`.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here and if this is an issue I should be raising with the developers of TeXlive please?

Comment: Do you still get this error if you enter in CMD the texworks command-line as-is in the error message? Do I understand correctly that if one ignores this message then everything else works perfectly fine?

Comment: Yeah I get the same error message when using `cmd`: `"C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows\texworks.exe" -stylesheet "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Programming\LaTeX\CSS Styles\darkbg.css" "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\scratchh.tex"` returns the same error message. Everything works perfectly, it is just the error message so it is less of an issue and more of a nuisance tbh, if it could be suppressed then that would be ideal without a root cause!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a new bug in TeXlive 2023, which might have to do with
errors in its installation process.

There is not much information to be found, but a similar error was observed
in this [post](https://okumuralab.org/tex/course/view.php?id=2)
in Chinese.
If Google Translate is to be trusted, some users have solved the error
by moving misplaced installation files to their correct folders and
installing a missing package.

My advice is to return to TeXlive 2022 and signal the bug to the
developers, then wait for it to be fixed.

If you have an urgent need to move to TeXlive 2023, you will have to
suffer this message. It's possible to write a AutoHotKey script that
will wait for this message and close it automatically, but this problem
might not be worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you, I will email the developers for an official solution on their end and will edit your answer with their response/when it is fixed and how to resolve it, appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

An update answer to my own question, in @harrymc's answer it is mentioned that you can use an AutoHotKey script to close the window. I noticed recently that if you right click the icon on the toolbar (the red blue and green cube on the taskbar):

[image]

and then click on the Microsoft ® Windows Based Script Host file, you can set it to sleep after `x` seconds. I have set it to 1 and it now automatically closes.